# One to Many Database Setup in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gqlquery

```
class Student(db.Model):
    teacher = db.ReferenceProperty(Teacher, collection_name='students')
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    zip_code = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    square_footage = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    month_entries = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)  

class Bill(db.Model):
    student = db.ReferenceProperty(Student, collection_name='bills')
    bill_month = db.DateProperty(required=True)
    energy = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

From my models setup shown above... I can easily show all the Bills stored using something like this:

```
bill = models.Bill.all()
for stubs in bill:
    print stubs.energy
    print stubs.student.name
```

But how do I list what Bills each student has?
In SQL I would say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Bill WHERE Student.Name = Samuel
```

I guess I don't understand how to retrieve the Bills given by ReferenceProperty. It doesn't seem so simple in GQL. How do I query by Reference Property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReferenceProperty creates an automatic query in the referenced entity (using the collection_name if you provided one, which you did):

```
sams_bills = Student.all().filter("name =", "Samuel").get().bills
```

`sams_bills` is now a db.Query for the bills, which you can call .fetch() on to retrieve one or more bills.

Answer (score 1):

I think the hardest thing for people with SQL experience to grok about App Engine is that a lot of stuff requires two queries to get the results you want.

```
student = Student.all().filter('name =', 'Samuel').get()
bill = Bill.all().filter('student =', student.key()).get()
```

The second hardest thing for people with SQL experience to grok is that hardly anyone uses GQL. ;)

Comment: Completely agree... I'm learning... yet when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The collection_name parameter of the db.ReferenceProperty "student" in the Bill class has already set up a query for you.  So all you have to do is this:

```
student = Student.all().filter('name =', 'Samuel').get()
for bill in student.bills:
    logging.info('Student %s Month:%s Energy:%d' % (student.name, str(bill.bill_month), bill.energy)
```

Now the results returned by the back-referenced query are unordered.  You can (if you have your indexes set up right) use .order() to return them in a particular order, or you can put them into a Set and sort them in memory (very fast) like this:

```
sorted_bills = []
for bill in student.bills:
    sorted_bills.append(bill)

# Sort additions by month then by amount (secondary key sorts first in code)
sorted_bills = sorted(sorted_bills, key=lambda Bill: Bill.energy, reverse=True)
sorted_bills = sorted(sorted_bills, key=lambda Bill: Bill.bill_month, reverse=False)
```

In this example, if a student had more than one bill with the same bill_month value, the largest bills would be sorted first (note the reverse=True parameter).